# Two classes but same object

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have 2 tables, tblA and tblB, with same fields and types. I get datas through linq to sql so I have 2 partial classes clsTblA and clsTblB.

I have a combo to choose tblA or tblB and I have to read in that table and do some query.

What I'am trying to do is evitate to duplicate code to run the same methods.
So now I have (in pseudo-code):

```
if (combo == "A")
{
  List<clsTblA> listUserNow = ctx.clsTblA.Where(p => p.blabla).ToList();
  List<clsTblA> listUserLastYear = ctx.clsTblA.Where(q => q.blabla).ToList();
}
if (combo == "B")
{
  List<clsTblB> listUserNow = ctx.clsTblB.Where(p => p.blabla).ToList();
  List<clsTblB> listUserLastYear = ctx.clsTblB.Where(q => q.blabla).ToList();
}
```

But I have in mind something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
SupClsTable clsTblX = null;
if (combo == A)
  clsTblX = new clsTblA();
if (combo == B)
  clsTblX = new clsTblB();

List<clsTblX> listUserNow = tblX.QueryForNow();
List<clsTblX> listUserLastYear = tblX.QueryForLastYear();
```

Does it exist something like this?
I also searched in design pattern but without results.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:
At this moment the code is like:

```
if (combo == A)
{
  using (DbDataContext ctx = new DbDataContext())
  {
      List<clsTblA> listUserNow = ctx.clsTblA.Where(p => p.blabla).ToList();
      List<clsTblA> listUserLastYear = ctx.clsTblA.Where(q => q.blabla).ToList();
  }
}
if (combo == B)
{
  using (DbDataContext ctx = new DbDataContext())
  {
      List<clsTblB> listUserNow = ctx.clsTblB.Where(p => p.blabla).ToList();
      List<clsTblB> listUserLastYear = ctx.clsTblB.Where(q => q.blabla).ToList();
  }
}
```

so I have twice listUserNow and listUserLastYear.
How can I let me return a unique

```
using (DbDataContext ctx = new DbDataContext()) 
{
    List<*something*> listUserNow = ctx.*something*.Where(p => p.blabla).ToList();
    List<*something*> listUserLastYear = ctx.*something*.Where(p => p.blabla).ToList();
}
```

indipendent from "if combo"?
Thanks in advence

Comment: Why aren't you using an interface? For that matter, if both classes are IDENTICAL, why are there two classes?

Comment: Remove second table(and class), add column(and property) like `type` with values `A` AND `B` ... now you have one table and one class ... problem solved (`Where(p => p.blablam && p.type="A")`)

Comment: tblA and tblB have been set from the stakeholder..

Comment: @CodeIT, the stakeholders give you requirements, not db implementation. If they insist on doing that, usually it's not a good sign

Comment: I can totally buy that there may be a good reasoon why you need two classes. I'd go for a common base class, and try and putas much as possible in there. Then have table A and table B classes as children. As little as possible in them, they just delegate to the base as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're looking for are Interfaces. i.e.

```
interface ISampleInterface
{
    void SampleMethod();
}

class ImplementationClass : ISampleInterface
{
    // Explicit interface member implementation: 
    void ISampleInterface.SampleMethod()
    {
        // Method implementation.
    }
}
```

You can learn more about that on the Microsoft documentation site [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface)

EDIT: To clearify. Once both Classes inerhit from the Interface you could write the following

```
if (combo == A)
  clsTblX = new clsTblA();
if (combo == B)
  clsTblX = new clsTblB();
```

as follows

```
IClsTable clsTbl = (combo == A)? new ClsTblA() : new ClsTblB() // example
```

and work with the `clsTbl` like you would've previously with `ClsTblA` or `ClsTblB` since both follow the same structure and have same properties and methods.

Maybe [this dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KhMeIw) helps you understand the concept of this solution.

Comment: My problem is create a (super) object that contains both classTblA and classTblB.

So that object can decide at runtime if it have to make work as A or as B.

Comment: @CodeIT Let both classes imlement that interface.

Comment: @CodeIT an interface lets you store every object that inerhits the interface.

Comment: @Vulpex Thanks for your interest.

Ok but when I have to call a query method of IClsTable, how can IClsTable "understand" if it have to work as ClsTblA or ClsTblB to return me a unique object?

Comment: @CodeIT You said both `ClsTblA` and `ClsTblB` are identical. If those could then inerhit from a Interface that represents the class structure. If you then `store` the objects in a `list<Interface>` you're able to invoke methods defined in the interface since the classes are ensured to have those methods. The methods can work differently in each class but they have to have the same structure.

Comment: @CodeIT Also the content stored in the `list<Interface>` still is the class you defined it as, you could still retrieve it by a simple `list<Interface>[index].GetType()` to identify what class exactly it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

While personally I think interfacing is better option for your use case, you could also implement something like this that will make it easy for you to extend. Same can be casted against interface as well. So every time a new combo is added just add a case and it extends easily.

```
public class ComboFactory
{
    public static SuperCombo GetComboClassInstance(string comboCode)
    {
        switch(comboCode)
        {
            case "A":
                return new ComboA();
            case "B":
                return new ComboB();
            //and so on
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this is what you need:

```
public interface iTbl
{
    int Property1 { get; set; }
    string Property2 { get; set; }

    void WhatAreYou();
}

public class clsTblA : iTbl
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public void WhatAreYou()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a clsTblA!");
    }
}

public class clsTblB : iTbl
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public void WhatAreYou()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a clsTblB!");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<iTbl> tbls = new List<iTbl>()
        {
            new clsTblA(),
            new clsTblB(),
            new clsTblB(),
            new clsTblA(),
            new clsTblA()
        };

        foreach (var tbl in tbls)
        {
            tbl.WhatAreYou();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I am a clsTblA!
I am a clsTblB!
I am a clsTblB!
I am a clsTblA!
I am a clsTblA!
```